# photo conversion 2d black and white to 3d rgb photo

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, data-structures, photo

I have an image
frame: array of unit8 (624, 832,3)

which I use an opencv function to get edges.

edge = cv.Canny(frame, 100, 200, 3, L2gradient=True)

and it converts the image to the black and white image.
edge: array of unit8 (624, 832)

I want the black and white image, but I don't want to change the structure,
I am ok to convert the "edge" the pervious size again.

Comment: It has not "converted" anything.  Your original image is still RGB.  The edge results are grayscale.  What do you expect to do with the edge image?  You can certainly convert it to RGB with `backtorgb = cv.cvtColor(edge,cv.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)`.

Comment: What is "unit8"?  Do you mean "uint8"? What do you mean by 3D?  Do you mean to see the edges in 3D or just 3 channels RGB? Please be more clear when you post questions.  Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).